# Get reference of ParameterInfo parameter

Tags: c#, reflection, stack

I have the method

```
     public void SomeMethod(string PersonName,int Age)
     {

        // get call stack
        StackTrace stackTrace = new StackTrace();

        // should equal "SomeMethod"
        var MethodName = stackTrace.GetFrame(0).GetMethod().Name;

        // should be ParameterInfo of parameter "PersonName"
        var firstParam = stackTrace.GetFrame(0).GetMethod().GetParameters()[0];

        // Here is where I get stuck !!!!!!!
        var t = firstParam.GetValue();
```

**How would I be able to get a reference to where firstParam parameter points to in order to get it's value?**

I know I could get that by PersonName but I will like to retrive that info through firstParam.

Comment: @Tejs: That should be an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reflection information doesnt contain data on the current state of the object, just metadata on the parameter info. Even when you have a `PropertyInfo` class, you have to provide an object for it to have any meaning of the value. You're better off simply using the provided value of the parameter.